# How to use the Azure Mobile Service API feature

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile, azure, azure-mobile-services

An **API** feature has been added to WAMS where I can define custom scripts. This seems to deprecate the previous practice of creating a script table. However, I couldn't find any description about how I can use it.

Which clients make this feature accessible? Can it be used from iOS or Javascript?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

And a couple more posts on this topic: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2013/06/14/custom-apis-in-azure-mobile-services.aspx (server side) and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2013/06/19/custom-api-in-azure-mobile-services-client-sdks.aspx (client side).

Also, since you tagged your question with ios, here's the code you'd use to call the API using an instance of the `MSClient` class:

If your API only deals with (receives / returns) JSON data:

```
MSClient *client = [MSClient clientWithApplicationURLString:@"https://your-service.azure-mobile.net"
                                             applicationKey:@"your-application-key"];
[client invokeApi:@"calculator/add"
             body:nil
       HTTPMethod:@"GET"
       parameters:@{@"x":@7, @"y":@8}  // sent as query-string parameters
          headers:nil
       completion:^(id result, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
}];
```

Or with a request body (POST):

```
[client invokeApi:@"calculator/sub"
             body:@{@"x":@7, @"y":@8}   // serialized as JSON in the request body
       HTTPMethod:@"POST"
       parameters:nil
          headers:nil
       completion:^(id result, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
}];
```

If your API deals with non-JSON data, you can use the other selector which takes / returns a `NSData` object:

```
NSData *image = [self loadImageFromSomePlace];
[client invokeApi:@"processImage"
             data:image
       HTTPMethod:@"POST"
       parameters:nil
          headers:nil
       completion:^(NSData *result, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
}];
```

Comment: Is there some latency between the published framework archive and the GitHub repository? https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-mobile-services The repo does not contain this addition yet.

Comment: It's usually in the repo a few days after the SDKs are published. I'd guess by early next week it should be there...

Comment: So I have tried exactly what you are showing and although I do get a result with two objects, they always show blank.  Ideas?


[self.client invokeAPI:@"pointsbygameperuser"
                 body:nil
           HTTPMethod:@"GET"
           parameters:@{@"Id":item}  // sent as query-string parameters
              headers:nil
           completion:^(NSArray *result, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
               NSLog(@"Result: %d", [result count]);
           }];

Answer (score 5):

this might help: [What’s new in Windows Azure Mobile Service : Api Script](http://jeremiedevillard.wordpress.com/2013/06/12/whats-new-in-windows-azure-mobile-service-api-script/)

Comment: Great finding! Please add a few lines of explanation to your answer to make it more self contained and I'll immediately accept it.

Answer (score 5):

i found this one help too:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/create-pull-notifications-dotnet

basically you can access your custom API using this end-point format:

https://service_name.azure-mobile.net/api/api_name

put this on your script:

```
exports.get = function(request, response) {    
    response.send(200, "Hello World");
};
```

and set your API permission on GET to allow ***everyone***, then you can use browser or fiddler to test your API by visiting the end-point:

https://service_name.azure-mobile.net/api/api_name

if you didn't change your permission, you have to put header code as below on your request:

```
GET https://service_name.azure-mobile.net/api/test HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-type: application/json
X-ZUMO-APPLICATION: your-manage-key-here
```